# Движение в godot node2d не работает

Tags: разработка-игр, 2d, godot, gdscript

Здравстуйте!
Создал скрипт на Godot Engine. Самый простой скрипт который можно создать для простого движения. По идеи он работает, но не правильно когда я нажимаю на клавишу он перемещается, единственная проблема в том что если удерживать эту же клавишу он не продолжит движение, прошу помочь.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export(int) var speed = 200
func _physics_process(delta):
    var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
        velocity.x += speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("left"):
        velocity.x -= speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("down"):
        velocity.y += speed
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up"):
        velocity.y -= speed
    velocity = velocity.normalized()
    move_and_slide(velocity * speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Input.is_action_just_pressed
```

поменять на

```
Input.is_action_pressed
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]